# How to print the sign + of a digit for positive numbers in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting

Is there a better way to print the + sign of a digit on positive numbers?

```
integer1 = 10
integer2 = 5
sign = ''
total = integer1-integer2
if total > 0: sign = '+'
print 'Total:'+sign+str(total)
```

0 should return 0 without +.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
>>> print "%+d" % (-1)
-1
>>>
>>> print "%+d" % (1)
+1
>>> print "%+d" % (0)
+0
>>>
```

Here is [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

** Update** If for whatever reason you can't use the `%` operator, you don't need a function:

```
>>> total = -10; print "Total:" + ["", "+"][total > 0] + str(total)
Total:-10
>>> total = 0; print "Total:" + ["", "+"][total > 0] + str(total)
Total:0
>>> total = 10; print "Total:" + ["", "+"][total > 0] + str(total)
Total:+10
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'm working with web.py templator and i'm not sure if i can use the string formatting % operator. Is there a Python method that return the sign of a given number?

Comment: Huh? You used the `%` operator in your question! Please edit your question so that it reflects your real requirement(s).

Comment: ("+" if total > 0 else "") is 6 more characters, but a bit more direct and (IMHO) clearer.

Comment: how can we do 0 should return 0 without +? `print "Total:" + ["", ""][total > 0] + str(total)`?

Answer (score 106):

Use the [new string format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings)

```
>>> '{0:+} number'.format(1)
'+1 number'
>>> '{0:+} number'.format(-1)
'-1 number'
>>> '{0:+} number'.format(-37)
'-37 number'
>>> '{0:+} number'.format(37)
'+37 number'
# As the questions ask for it, little trick for not printing it on 0
>>> number = 1
>>> '{0:{1}} number'.format(number, '+' if number else '')
'+1 number'
>>> number = 0
>>> '{0:{1}} number'.format(number, '+' if number else '')
'0 number'
```

It's recommended over the `%` operator

Comment: 0 -> `+0`, not what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've noticed the moment I hit the button. I've corrected it.

Comment: Nice answer!  You don't need to explicitly index the components inside format(), so `{:+}` and `{:{}}` are sufficient.  They also make better emoticons.

Comment: Would sill print the sign for `-0.0`.

Comment: It turns out f"strings" also allow nested replacement fields, so `f"{number:{'+' if number else ''}}"` also works.

Comment: With percent it's `{:+.1%}` which for examples gives '+11.1%' for `f'{0.111:+.1%}'`

Answer (score 42):

From python 3.6 onwards:

```
>>> integer1 = 10
>>> integer2 = 5
>>> total = integer1-integer2
>>> print(f'Total: {total:+}')
Total: +5
```

or:

```
for i in range(-1,2):
    print (f' {i} becomes {i:+}')
```

outputs:

```
 -1 becomes -1
 0 becomes +0
 1 becomes +1
```

Comment: I note the 0 returns `+0` but personally I prefer this.

Comment: How would you do this with float numbers?

Comment: `f"{123.456:+.2f}"` => `'+123.46'`