# Python: Superscript only prints beginning of float

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to print a result in pyplot using plt.legend, but the superscript

```
${0}^{1}
```

prints my {1} float (and even string) as the first part of that float(or string)

```
tit='The resonance position is ${0}^{1}$'.format(xl[0],xp,xm)
```

the result on the image(since I can't post a screenshot, I'll type it out:

```
                               + 
The resonance position is 8.71   0.19
```

or if I get rid of the '+'

```
                               0 
The resonance position is 8.71   .19
```

whilst {1}, i.e. xp (a string) is

```
'+0.19'
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my first time using StackOverflow, I searched for this specific question and problem and couldn't find anything. So if this question had already been answered - I'm sorry!

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: The thrid format string parameter is useless...

Comment: @wenzul sorry, didn't write the rest of the code. I'm using it as well, but need to first figure out the first two, the third is being used as a subscript

Comment: @wenzul Sorry, it's going to be a bit of a lengthy explanation:

This data is calculated in a for/if cycle. Problem is after the cycle finds the correct data it gives out 8.710000000006 instead of a basic 8.71, but for some reason, when converted to string that tail of zero's disappears. So my process comes down to str(result) and then converting it back float(said string). It's a very stupid and cumbersome process which so far is the only way to solve this stupid problem. With your method (with the {0} and {1} being floats right away) gives me the same problem as I posted - 1st part of float

Comment: Delete the string conversion and use my format string example in my answer. Using strings to cut zeros is not a good choice and often a beginner's mistake. Therefore there are string format functions and methods. You could post your code at http://repl.it/ and post the link.

Comment: @wenzul Yes! It worked! ~~But my only request now is: is it possible to add a '+' or '-'? I'm using both superscript and subscript to show uncertainties in data~~ Never mind! It worked, I just put the '+'/'-' in their corresponding {} http://i.imgur.com/YWFw2H1.png

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can add a explicit [`+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763432/how-to-print-the-sign-of-a-digit-for-positive-numbers-in-python) behind the `%`.

Comment: @wenzul Thank you so much! It all worked, now I can resume my work. It's been a bit of a clustercuss, glad StackOverflow helped out so fast.

Comment: If the answer satisfies mark the answer and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use integer/float values no strings. You can use `%d`, `%f` and `%s` etc.
Just stay at the natural datatype. Conversion to string is not necessary. Using `format` is slower than just use string formatting with `%`

```
"${%+.2f}^{%+.2f}$" % (float("8.71"), float("+0.19"))
```

You could kinf of "debug" it if you just print the string. You have to look that there have to be parentesis.

Comment: Didn't work :( Same problem happens, prints only the first part of the float - the zero http://i.imgur.com/0fTlhnl.png

Comment: @Tigs Did you tried the right? I delete the `format` case. Use the second... and may post more code if its not working.

Answer (score 2):

In latex it would be as $8.5^{9.67}$, if not it will only upper the first digit, as you report. So you will need to change:

```
${0}^{1}$
```

To:

```
${0}^{{1}}$
```

(Or ${0}^{{1}}$ not sure.)

Before formating it.

Comment: Thank you for replying!

I tried that just now, but still got a familiar error:


ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string