# How do I convert a dataframe column filled with numbers to strings in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, data-conversion

I have a dataframe `dfA` that has a column `diff` where every value is a number, example:

```
dfA['diff']
```

Outputs:

```
88    -120.0
89    -130.0
90    -105.0
91    -115.0
92    -120.0
93    -110.0
94    -120.0
95    -115.0
96    -120.0
97    -105.0
98    -130.0
99    -115.0
100   -115.0
101    120.0
102   -155.0
103    115.0
104   -150.0
105   -190.0
106    140.0
107    170.0
108   -240.0
109    115.0
110   -160.0
111   -125.0
112   -110.0
115   -205.0
116    150.0
117   -155.0
118    115.0
Name: diff, dtype: float64
```

I want to:

- Remove the decimal
- Add a + sign in front if `diff` is a positive number
- And finally convert to a string

Example:

```
88    -120
89    -130
90    -105
91    -115
92    -120
93    -110
94    -120
95    -115
96    -120
97    -105
98    -130
99    -115
100   -115
101   +120
102   -155
103   +115
104   -150
105   -190
106   +140
107   +170
108   -240
109   +115
110   -160
111   -125
112   -110
115   -205
116   +150
117   -155
118   +115
```

- I've tried using the `int()` function but I receive a `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`
- I'm not sure how to add the '+' sign to positive numbers
- I do know that `dfA['diff'] = dfA['diff'].apply(str)` is the string
  conversion portion

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to integers and strings to helper Series `s`, so possible compare original column for greater like `0` with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) for prepend `+`:

```
s = dfA['diff'].astype(int).astype(str)
dfA['diff'] = s.mask(dfA['diff'].gt(0), '+' + s)

print (dfA)
     diff
98   -130
99   -115
100  -115
101  +120
102  -155
103  +115
104  -150
```

With formatting:

```
dfA['diff'] = dfA['diff'].map(lambda x: '{0:+}'.format(int(x)))
```

Comment: or use format string function https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763589/7483073 to get a string with sign and just apply it to the complete column

Comment: This added the '+' and did the conversion to string but the decimal is still there

Comment: @sportzcode - can you test `dfA['diff'].astype(int).astype(str)` ?

Comment: That works but now when `dfA['diff'] = s.mask(dfA['diff'].gt(0), '+' + s)` is run I receive `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: @sportzcode - is your code `s = dfA['diff'].astype(int).astype(str)` or `dfA['diff'] = dfA['diff'].astype(int).astype(str)` ?

Comment: The code is: `dfA['diff'] = dfA['diff'].astype(int).astype(str)`

`s = dfA['diff'].astype(str)`

`dfA['diff'] = s.mask(dfA['diff'].gt(0), '+' + s)`

Comment: The decimal is still there when i remove that 1st piece of code

Comment: @sportzcode - need `s = dfA['diff'].astype(int).astype(str) dfA['diff'] = s.mask(dfA['diff'].gt(0), '+' + s)`

Comment: Your code `s = dfA['diff'].astype(str)`, is necessary `s = dfA['diff'].astype(int).astype(str)`

Comment: I added the formatting code above and it worked! Thank you very much!