# Addition and Subtraction of Complex Numbers using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, oop

1. Define the class 'comp' that represents the Real and Imaginary parts of a complex number. For example, for the complex number "2+3i", 2 is the real part, and 3 is the imaginary part. Hint:Define the initializer method, `__init__`, that takes 2 values and assigns them to the above 2 attributes, respectively.
2. Define a method 'add' inside the class 'comp', which determines the sum of two complex numbers and Print the sum as "Sum of the two Complex numbers :35+47i"
3. Define a method 'sub' inside the class 'comp', which determines the difference of two complex numbers and Print the difference as "Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :-33-43i" Note: Subtract the second complex number from the first.

This is my code:

```
class comp:
  
    def __init__(self, real, imag):
        self.real=real
        self.imag=imag

    def add(self,other):
        print('Sum of the two Complex numbers :{}+{}i'.format(self.real+other.real,self.imag+other.imag))
    
    def sub(self, other):
        print('Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :{}+{}i'.format(self.real-other.real, self.imag-other.imag))
```

Output:

```
Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :-2+-2i
```

Expected output:

```
Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :-2-2i
```

Can you help me to print the expected output?

Comment: Only print a `+` if the imaginary part is positive.

Answer (score 2):

The operator is hard coded in the format string (`{}+{}i`).  If you replace that `+` sign and make that a variable, too, you're almost done.

Note that the python `str.format` specifiers also allow you to always print the sign (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763589/6610)

I suspect this is homework so I won't fill it in for you :).